# How can I reduce google sheets lag by replacing thousands of cell by cell formula calculations with an elegant script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

first time posting, so bear with me.

I have successfully designed a [google sheet that automatically creates a crop map](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-RkXabogdd6AzOlfevhZciXxgfbvvIdhTNTDBGmEa1A/edit?usp=sharing) based on the crop plan in another tab ('Successions')

In 'Successions' the following columns are relevant:
Column A - Succession ID
Column C - Row ID
Column R - Planting Date
Column W - Harvest Date

In "Map 1A" I have created a map of our field, with Column B representing the Row ID and the columns to the right each representing a week of the year, whose start dates are defined in row 2.

My goal is to map each succession on the appropriate row for the duration that it will be in the ground (Planting Date to Harvest Date). I will have different successions occupying the same row during different date ranges.

I accomplished this in three steps:

**Step 1**
Every cell (except the left most column) contains a formula that returns and text joins (if multiple results) any successions in that row during that week - if an only if the value it would return is different than the value the cell to left would return. The result is that the succession ID is only displayed on the week that it starts. The formula in these cells is:

`=Iferror(If((Textjoin(" / ",True,FILTER(Successions!$A$2:$A$647,RegExMatch(Successions!$C$2:$C$647,$B3),Successions!$R$2:$R$647<D$2,Successions!$W$2:$W$647>D$2)))=(Textjoin(" / ",True,Iferror(FILTER(Successions!$A$2:$A$647,RegExMatch(Successions!$C$2:$C$647,$B3),Successions!$R$2:$R$647<C$2,Successions!$W$2:$W$647>C$2),""))),"",(Textjoin(" / ",True,FILTER(Successions!$A$2:$A$647,RegExMatch(Successions!$C$2:$C$647,$B3),Successions!$R$2:$R$647<D$2,Successions!$W$2:$W$647>D$2)))),"")`

The code for the leftmost column, which I did not want to check the cell to the left is:

`=Iferror((Textjoin(" / ",True,FILTER(Successions!$A$2:$A$647,RegExMatch(Successions!$C$2:$C$647,$B3),Successions!$R$2:$R$647<C$2,Successions!$W$2:$W$647>C$2))),"")`

**Step 2**
Because every cell contains a formula, I could not get the succession ID to spill into the adjacent cell and thus be readable. To solve this, I have an adjacent tab called "Map Final" that mirrors "Map 1A" via an Array Formula. Because it does not carry over formulas just values, it allows text to spill over.

**Step 3**
Conditional formatting is applied to "Map Final" via the Custom Formula function. There will be a rule for each crop type. Each succession is automatically colored the color of its crop type, and the color fills all cells for the duration of the succession.

**My question is this:**
How could I accomplish this same mapping in a more efficient way?  Currently any update to Successions takes 30 seconds to a minute to update. The progress bars are killing me and basically make this really cool tool unusable for crop planning purposes, during which we are going back and forth from data to map frequently to make placement decisions.

1. Do you think this is possible using a custom script that pushes data rather than pulling data?
2. Would it render faster, or is the way I'm doing it the most efficient way?

While that is my main question, I am certainly open to any advice you have for improving speed by simply refining my current method.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Give it a try to the following to see if it is more efficient: create an intermediate sheet using IMPORTRANGE(URL of first sheet) and then take the information from there. Using IMPORTRANGE might be faster than simply calling the data from one sheet into another.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Are you referring to Step 2 above? Replace the Arrayformula that calls the cells with an importrange to call the same cells? Or are you saying to move "Map Final" to another spreadsheet and then populate it using Importrange?

Comment: Yes, try it with the step 2 replacing the Array formula with the import range. Let me know how that works. I also see that you are using a script now, did that reduce your timing?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf I'm not using a script now. The whole point of this post was trying to figure how I could use a script instead of a formula in every cell plus 20 conditional formatting rules. Changing the arrayformula to an importrange did not help in any significant way. It still takes 4 or 5 minutes for the map to render. I hope someone will chime in with ideas for how to do this with google scripts using arrays for greater efficiency.

Comment: Hi! Indeed you are using a scipt. Go to **Tools-> Script Editor**. Could you please summarise me what is this script intended for as you are mentioning that is not for the purpose of your question? Is it just for merging/unmering cells? Btw its not lagging that much when I use it. (Just a few seconds).